# Where is my current graph db file?

Tags: neo4j

I am editing a graph in Neo4j Brower on one computer. If I want to start a new graph in Browser, how to make sure the current one won't be destroy? Also, if I want to copy the current graph to another computer, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the path in your configuration file. Take a look right [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-define-my-graphdb-at-a-path-other-than-under-neo4j-home-for-windows/). You can also copy the files of all your graphs (for example the default.graphdb or graph.db directory) to replicate them or to move them to another directory.

Comment: what do you mean by "start browser in a new directory". Currently, I start neo4j by executing "./bin/neo4j start" and then start a browser.

Comment: Im going to edit the answer. Keep on startkng it like always you just have to edit the config